# Google map api V2 Marker Issue

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-2, marker

I have the following code

```
var marker;
var marker_list = [];
                    for (iLoopIndex=0;iLoopIndex<10;iLoopIndex++)
                    {
                        centerPoint = new GLatLng(32+iLoopIndex,68+iLoopIndex);
                        alert(centerPoint);
                        map.setCenter(centerPoint);

                        blueIcon = new GIcon(G_DEFAULT_ICON);
                        blueIcon.image = "truck.png";
                        blueIcon.iconSize = new GSize(40, 20);

                        // Set up our GMarkerOptions object
                        markerOptions = { icon:blueIcon };
                        //map.addOverlay(new GMarker(centerPoint, markerOptions));
                        marker = new GMarker(centerPoint, markerOptions);

                        GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                        marker.openInfoWindowHtml("iLocator <b>"+Myarr[2]+"</b>");
                        marker_list.push(marker);
                     });
                        map.addOverlay(marker);
                    }//End for
```

This Code make 10 markers on Google map, now I want to remove the markers, following is the code to remove the markers.

```
for (iLoopIndex=0;iLoopIndex<marker_list.length;iLoopIndex++)
{
    map.removeOverlay(marker_list[iLoopIndex]);
}
```

This code is not working its only remove the infowindow from the marker but not removing the image. Kindly guide me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: It is good time to upgrade to GoogleMaps v3 as totally changed from v2. Most of the developers may not able to help you too. It may worth to debug with firebug for map object after removeOverlay called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pushing your markers into your marker_list array inside the callback function for the GEvent Listener that you registered.. Your array will only be populated with Markers that had their InfoWindow triggered.

Move "marker_list.push(marker);" to the line above "map.addoverlay(marker);" ie..

```
  GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                    marker.openInfoWindowHtml("iLocator <b>"+Myarr[2]+"</b>");
                 });
                    marker_list.push(marker);
                    map.addOverlay(marker);
                }//End for
```

Comment: there is one more issue which I am facing that the info window display only on one marker.